# Looping through an array and add up with same value of a key

Tags: php, arrays

This is the sample json encoded array-

```
[
    {"item_id":"8057","category":"MEN'S CLOTHING","quantity":"3.000"},
    {"item_id":"22647","category":"WOMEN'S CLOTHING","quantity":"7.000"},        
    {"item_id":"1556","category":"MEN'S CLOTHING","quantity":"2.000"},
    {"item_id":"4179","category":"WOMEN'S CLOTHING","quantity":"1.000"},
    {"item_id":"21218","category":"WOMEN'S CLOTHING","quantity":"2.000"}
]
```

I want to add up `quantity` with same `category`.

Need final result something like-

```
"MEN'S CLOTHING" : 5,
"WOMEN'S CLOTHING": 10
```

Note: the value of key 'category' is dynamic

Comment: that's a `json` string, use `json_decode` to convert it to a php array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
$dataArray = json_decode($jsonArray, true);
     $allValuesWithCount = array(); 
    foreach($dataArray as $arrayValues) {    
        $allValuesWithCount[$arrayValues['category']] += $arrayValues['quantity'];
     } 
    print_r($allValuesWithCount);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using below code:

```
    $json = json_decode($string,true);

    $allCount = [];
    foreach ($json as $key => $value){
        $allCount[$value['category']] += $value['quantity'];
    }
    foreach ($allCount as $category => $value){
        echo $category ." : ".$value."<br>";
    }
```

But When I run it in different PHP version through the console, it gives the warnings and displayed following result:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: MEN'S CLOTHING in /home/akshay/so.php on line 15
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /home/akshay/so.php:0
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: WOMEN'S CLOTHING in /home/akshay/so.php on line 15 
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /home/akshay/so.php:0

```
MEN'S CLOTHING : 5
WOMEN'S CLOTHING : 10
```

Comment: When I am running it on my browser with PHP version 5.6 and FPM, it gives me `Undefined Index` error.

Comment: Also I have tried different PHP versions, it was just warning for both categories.